# Wrong top statement declaration in scala

Tags: scala

I have the following error, can anyone help me with that?

```
sealed trait MyWhitelist
object MyWhitelist {
  case object Update extends MyWhitelist
}

case class Whitelist(accountId: String, ruleName: String)
class AuthorizedServicesImpl(
    val doWhitelist: Map[MyWhitelist: => Set[Whitelist]]) //wrong top statement declaration
    {}
```

Comment: What is this: `Map[MyWhitelist: => Set[Whitelist]]` Maybe you meant `Map[MyWhitelist, Set[Whitelist]]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is because the compiler thinks `MyWhitelist` is being declared as a variable with a type of `() => Set[Whitelist]`. The colon is unnecessary. Also, `Map` takes 2 type parameters.

The comment by @Luis is probably what you want, or maybe `Map[MyWhitelist, () => Set[Whitelist]]`.